# Trying to decode and recode Perl Statistics::Regression code to R

Tags: r, perl

I have some perl code I am trying to understand. I can figure most of it out. The part I am having an issue translating to R is my `@theta = $reg->theta();` What is the theta part had how would I get that from an R code?

```
foreach my $id (keys(%$row_col_values)) {
    my $reg = Statistics::Regression->new( "title", [ "intercept", "slope"] );
    foreach my $row (keys(%$row_ids)) {
        foreach my $col (keys(%$col_ids)) {
            # Add data points
            if ($row_col_testplot_means->{$id}{$row}{$col} && $row_col_values->{$id}{$row}{$col}) {
                $reg->include( $row_col_testplot_means->{$id}{$row}{$col}, [ 1.0, $row_col_values->{$id}{$row}{$col}]);
            }
        }
    }
    my @theta = $reg->theta();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the manual for Statistics::Regression:

https://metacpan.org/pod/Statistics::Regression

You will see that theta most likely is the R's `coef()` of your model (the coefficients).

See also the source where the theta method is defined:

https://metacpan.org/release/Statistics-Regression/source/Regression.pm#L448

It says outright that its the coefficients.

According to Peter Flom's answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34903/what-does-theta-mean) the greek letter theta is used to denote the set of estimated parameters from an ordinary least squares regression.

Comment: Name                   Theta       StdErr  T-stat
[0='intercept']       2.3019       0.1689   13.63
[1='slope']           0.1162       0.0598    1.94                                                                                         ah yes THETA is the slope and the coef